# ¿En donde guardar codigo HTML?

Tags: php, oracle

estoy guardando codigo HTML en mi base de datos ORACLE, pero lei que es una mala idea guardar todo ese codigo en la base de datos. Así que me gustaría que me orienten en donde se tiene que guardar realmente. El sistema que estoy haciendo son acordeones en donde el administradoer puede crear tantos acordeones cuanto quiera, y presionar el botón guadar, todo ese codigo generado se guarda en la base de datos. Y se cargará en otra página en donde estará mostrando los acordeones que ha creado el administrador.

Comment: Entonces quitare el mensaje de error para evitar confunsiones

Comment: Ese error lo pondré en otra pregunta, ya que juntar 2 dudas generarán más confusiones. Gracias @Aprendiz

Comment: No conozco mucho acerca de PHP, me dedico mucho más a .net core, pero se me ocurre que podrías implementar una carpeta local privada que contenga todos los archivos HTML y de ahí te generes una función/método que te permita leer todo el html y lo retorne en el front, además así no vas a sobrecargar el servidor de la DB, que con cadenas de cerca de 50mil caracteres no le debe ser de su mayor agrado, he visto que se usa almacenar HTML en la DB pero con fragmentos chicos por ejemplo para el desarrollo de una SPA o Web dinámica, saludos

Comment: Hola @GianlucaFiore, tengo una duda con respecto a tu opinión, cómo se haría con respecto a las actualizaciones que realice el administrador. Cuando cambie algo, eso se actualizará en la carpeta privada de los usuarios?

Answer (score 2):

No conozco mucho acerca de PHP, me dedico mucho más a .net core, pero se me ocurre que podrías:

- implementar una carpeta local privada que contenga todos los archivos HTML
- de ahí te generes una función/método que te permita leer todo el html y lo retorne en el front

Además así no vas a sobrecargar el servidor de la DB, que con cadenas de cerca de 50mil caracteres no le debe ser de su mayor agrado, he visto que se usa almacenar HTML en la DB pero con fragmentos chicos por ejemplo para el desarrollo de una SPA o Web dinámica

Comment: Hola @GianlucaFiore, tengo una duda con respecto a tu respuesta, cómo se haría con respecto a las actualizaciones que se realicen más adelante. Si el administrador cambia el código HTML, eso se actualizará en la carpeta privada de todos los usuarios?

Comment: sí, no tendrías diferencia en lo demás que desees hacer, podés utilizar la carpeta local como almacenamiento en vez de la base de datos, siempre suponiendo la mejor práctica que sólo el sistema tiene acceso a la raíz del servidor, y en tu sistema supongo que tendrás un sistema de login y roles o niveles de acceso que te dirá si te permite o no acceder a tales recursos del sistema, en este caso: Entrar y editar un archivo local HTML